# SU Retag Request: [external-harddrive] --> [external-hard-drive]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I asked a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/83513/what-can-i-do-with-a-large-hard-drive) about external HDDs recently, and noticed the hard-drive tag and the external-harddrive tag are totally inconsistent. Any chance of a retag?

Comment: Why the downvote? I guess you could retag hard-drive to harddrive, but that looks awful!

Comment: duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32574/retag-request-on-superuser-rename-external-harddrive-to-external-hard-drive ... i'm all for it, but i fear this request will meet the same fate.

Comment: Apparently it did! Any chance of a reconsideration, Diago? Or a better retagging? Inconsistency drives me mad :(

Answer (score 1):

Synonyms exist:

[image]